# Cannot extract all the "feed" information(Pictures) from facebook graph API

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I am trying to extract information through facebook API into my ionic app. It shows the messages and dates correctly into my app but no images! I have uploaded the code and demo pictures in here.

Code:

```
.controller('FeedCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, OpenFB, $ionicLoading) {

$scope.show = function () {
    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading User Feed(s)...'
    });
};
$scope.hide = function () {
    $scope.loading.hide();
};

function loadFeed() {
    $scope.show();
    OpenFB.get('/me/feed', {
            limit: 30
        })
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.hide();
            $scope.items = result.data;
            // Used with pull-to-refresh
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            $scope.hide();
            alert(data.error.message);
        });
}

     **[<!---ionic---->][1]**

    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="list card">
     <div class="item item-avatar">
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ item.from.id }}/picture" />
      <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{item.created_time | date:'MMM d, y h:mma'}}</p>
     </div>
     <div class="item item-body">
       <p ng-if="item.story">{{item.story}}</p>
       <p>{{item.message}}</p>
       <h2>{{item.from.id}}</h2>
       <img ng-if="item.picture" ng-src="{{item.picture}}" />
     </div>
    </div>
```

And [image]

Comment: Always use `ng-src` to prevent bad requests for thiose url's before they are compiled. Look in browser dev tools network to see what is actually being requested also. Inspect the live html to see if the compiled url looks as you expect too.

Comment: Hello, David thanks for your answer. I have tried all already. The problem is in the link this portion {{ item.from.id }} is not working. Don't know what's the cause?

Comment: That 404 is not using compiled url as suggested `ng-src` would allow. Figure out how to open one in a browser directly and then fix the html value accordingly. Or perhaps you don't have the right data property either